# How do I convert m2ts video files?

Tags: video, software-rec, m2ts

I've imported videos from my Panasonic SD10 camera using the HD Writer software provided with the camera. Each video has three files with the following extensions: cont, iis & m2ts.

The mt2s looks like the video file, when I open it up in Windows Movie Maker the video is blank. The video is there when I view it using HD Writer, there doesn't appear to be any options to convert the video into any other format.

Can you recommend any software (free, open source) that I can use to convert these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[M2TS Converter](http://www.m2tsconverter.com/) can convert M2TS video files to all popular video files including AVI, VOB, WMV, MPEG, MP4, iPod, MOV, M4V, FLV, 3GP on Windows with excellent output quality and high conversion speed.

[image]